# ServiceStack/Client and "Reading from "node:fs" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme)." error

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to upgrade from the 1.X ServiceStack/Client library to the 2.X version 
I got the following error when running "ng build" after the upgrade (latest 1.X works fine):

```
node:fs - Error: Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:fs" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.

node:path - Error: Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:path" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
```

What could potentially be the problem?

This is the list of installed npm packages:

```
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@14.2.10
+-- @angular/animations@14.2.12
+-- @angular/cli@14.2.10
+-- @angular/common@14.2.12
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@14.2.12
+-- @angular/compiler@14.2.12
+-- @angular/core@14.2.12
+-- @angular/forms@14.2.12
+-- @angular/language-service@14.2.12
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@14.2.12
+-- @angular/platform-browser@14.2.12
+-- @angular/router@14.2.12
+-- @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@13.1.1
+-- @ngx-translate/core@14.0.0
+-- @ngx-translate/http-loader@7.0.0
+-- @popperjs/core@2.11.6
+-- @servicestack/client@2.0.7
+-- @types/google-libphonenumber@7.4.23
+-- @types/node@18.14.6
+-- angular-code-input@1.6.0
+-- bootstrap@5.2.3
+-- core-js@3.29.0
+-- google-libphonenumber@3.2.32
+-- jquery@3.6.3
+-- node-fs@0.1.7
+-- node-libs-browser@2.2.1
+-- rxjs@7.8.0
+-- ts-node@10.9.1
+-- tslib@2.5.0
+-- tslint@6.1.3
+-- typescript@4.8.4
`-- zone.js@0.12.0
```

npm -v: 9.6.0

node -v: v18.14.2

That is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "portal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "echo Starting 'ng serve'... && ng serve",
    "start:iis": "echo Starting 'ng build --watch'... && ng build --watch",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run Portal:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "14.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "14.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "14.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "14.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "14.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "14.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "14.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "14.2.12",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "13.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@servicestack/client": "^2.0.7",
    "angular-code-input": "^1.6.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "core-js": "^3.29.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.32",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "node-fs": "^0.1.7",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.5.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "14.2.10",
    "@angular/cli": "14.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "14.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "14.2.12",
    "@types/google-libphonenumber": "^7.4.23",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.6",
    "node-libs-browser": "^2.2.1",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "tslint": "~6.1.3"
  }
}
```

That's my tsconfig:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "types": [ "node" ],
    "target": "es2020"
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

That's my angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Portal": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "progress": false,
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true,
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [ "google-libphonenumber", "@servicestack/client" ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Portal:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Portal:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Portal:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [ "src/styles.css" ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [ "src/assets" ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist-server",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        }
      }
    },
    "Portal-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Portal:serve"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error should be resolved in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client/commit/3090abafe7a8cc505069d3e6534fb823f7c04220) which is available from the latest v2.0.8 of [@servicestack/client](https://docs.servicestack.net/javascript-client).

Comment: Thanks, v2.0.8 was released a few hours after my question. The problem, which prevented the build, is resolved. However, it is now replaced with two warnings (but at least it compiles):

Build at: 2023-03-04T12:29:31.177Z - Hash: dc963a6f86967119 - Time: 765ms

./node_modules/@servicestack/client/dist/index.js:3546:65-76 - Warning: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

./node_modules/@servicestack/client/dist/index.js:3549:69-80 - Warning: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Comment: The warnings are a result of the workaround to resolve the first error, which is unavoidable despite being inside an unused code path.